# remove white space from top of pdf using pdf.js

Tags: html, css, pdf.js

This is my first time working with pdf.js. I am trying to display a pdf inside a  element which is inside a div:

```html
 <div class="col-sm-9 pdf_col_main ms-3 ">
  <canvas id="pdf-canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
```

The pdf renders fine except it has a massive margin/white space at the top.
For the css, the display is set to block and the width:100%. The margins and padding are all set to 0. It sounds like this is an issue many people have and I am yet to find a solution (other than people saying to set display to block...which does not work for me). I get the sense that this may be an unfixable problem?

You can set the coordinates for where an image is displayed in canvas, or crop an image but none of these solutions apply to a pdf.

These are pdfs uploaded by clients so not feasible to edit them in an outside program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is basically the same code I posted above? To be clear the whitespace/margin is a part of the pdf and is thus inside the canvas. My prior research indicated that pdfs may have header and footer formatting built in that is not stripped when pdf.js renders it onto a canvas. I am trying to see if there is a work around. Traditional approaches (with images) like altering the coordinates or cropping don't appear to be available with the pdf render. I found a way to set the canvas margin to a negative, but this seems less than ideal.

Comment: Try setting `->SetTopMargin(0);` and  `setPrintHeader(false);`